# Query with FIND_IN_SET and array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, find-in-set

I have two tables `tbl_user` and `tbl_projects`

```
tbl_user
+-----+------+--------+
| id  | name | skills |
+-----+------+--------+
|  u1 | x    | s1,s2  |
|  u2 | y    | s2,s3  |
|  u3 | z    | s3,s1  |
+-----+------+--------+

tbl_projects
+-----+--------+
| id  | kills  |
+-----+--------+
|  p1 | s2     |
|  p2 | s1,s3  |
|  p3 | s3     |
+-----+--------+
```

For my application I want a sql query for list out all projects those which are match with the user skill

example, If i select the user u1 the result will be like

```
+-----+--------+
| id  | kills  |
+-----+--------+
|  p1 | s2     |
|  p2 | s1,s3  |
+-----+--------+
```

Comment: The architecture is wrong for matching, You need to normalize `skills` as  a different table and have association with `user` and `project`. That way, it will be easy to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People better than I can help you build an SQL query to get you there. The way your tables look though, you will always have to build complex queries to pull out useful information.  My advice, especially if you are still early in your project, is to change your table structure to make querying easier.

For instance, the tables below reflect the info in your OP in a structure that will make your life much much easier.

**tbl_users**: holds details that have a one-to-one relationship with each user

```
userID|name|email...
 u1   |  x | ...
 u2   |  y | ...
 u3   |  z | ...
```

**tbl_skills**: details that have a one-to-one relationship with each skill

```
skillID
s1
s2
s3
```

**tbl_projects**: details that have a one-to-one relationship with each project

```
pID|   title   | deadline
p1 | project a | 2016-08-15
p2 | project b | 2017-01-01
p3 | project c | 2015-08-22
```

**tbl_user_skills**: Each record has one user and one skill, both of which are foreign keys to this table (primary keys in `tbl_users` and `tbl_skills` respectively). It should have a `UNIQUE` index on `(userID,skillID)` to prevent duplicate entries.

```
userID|skillID
 u1   | s1
 u1   | s2
 u2   | s2
 u2   | s3
 u3   | s1
 u3   | s3
```

**tbl_project_skills** Each record has one project and one skill, both of which are foreign keys to this table (primary keys in `tbl_project` and `tbl_skills` respectively). It should have a `UNIQUE` index on `(pID,skillID)` to prevent duplicate entries.

```
pID|skillID
p1 |s2
p2 |s1
p2 |s3
p3 |s3
```

Once everything is organized this way, your queries will be much faster and much simpler to build. In fact, if you understand bitflag operations, you could condense this considerably (eg: have all skills from a user as one field in `tbl_users` but instead of `s1,s2` you would use bits).

To get all projects with the skills of user `u1`:

```
SELECT p.pID, p.title
FROM tbl_projects p
LEFT JOIN tbl_project_skills ps ON p.pID = ps.pID
LEFT JOIN tbl_user_skills us ON ps.skillID = us.skillID
WHERE us.userID='u1'
GROUP BY p.pID
```

Result

```
pID| title
p1 | project a
p2 | project b
```

Comment: The id columns in the final two tables serve no purpose.

Comment: @Strawberry None that answers the specific question in the OP, but I always have a primary key in every table I build because I want each record in each table to be uniquely identifiable. It's harder to add a primary key later, if your application comes to need it.

Comment: You have a perfectly good natural key in both of those tables. There's no need for a surrogate.

Comment: @BeetleJuice, the two last tables should a UNIQUE index. One on userID|skillID and one on pID|skillID. Having those indexes makes each row "uniquely identifiable" as you want it. Current id column is completely redundant.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for the feedback. I'll read up on the pros and cons.

Comment: @alexsmith I agree fully. I've added that note to the answer

Comment: @BeetleJuice Thank you for your response. But it is a existing project. I can't change the DB structure. Only I can do the php coding. What can I do for the same?